# Play 2.2: do not understand one part of the application.conf config related to DB

Tags: scala, playframework

I am working on my play app which uses anorm to access my DB.
So here goes the part of my application.conf

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bubusik?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
db.default.user=root
db.default.password="*********"
```

If I remove the `?characterEncoding=UTF-8` part then anything not English language will be as ???????? questions marks in the DB.
So I am wondering what exactly this piece of config sets up?
Please note that default charset of my DB schema is UTF-8 as well as for all it's tables.

Answer (score 1):

This part of the configuration file sets up the JDBC driver, which connects your application to the database. The db.default.url is used to set up the connection to your MySql database. Since Play/Scala run on the Java Virtual Machine, your application holds strings in a UTF-16 encoding. The characterEncoding parameter defines which character set the database expects to receive text strings in.

So ?characterEncoding=UTF-8 informs the driver code that it needs to map strings from UTF-16 to UTF-8 before sending the JDBC request to MySql. If the target encoding does not match the encoding of the database then the format of the string in the JDBC request will be decoded using the wrong set of rules.

For more details see: [Using Character Sets and Unicode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html)

Comment: Perfect explanation. Thanks. I did not know that default encoding would be UTF-16 in this case.